# numerical test for matrix multiplication

Tags: c++

I was wondering how to implement a test function in c++ for a matrix multiplication. 
Is there a common way, how to do that?
I know that it should have something to do with the Inverse, but I'm not sure how to implement this properly.

Let's say this would be the multiplication I'd like to test:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  //#include <stdint.h>

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // allocate space for empty matrix A[row][col]
  // access to matrix elements possible with:
  // - A[row][col]
  // - A[0][row*col]


  float **alloc_mat(int row, int col)
  {
      float **A1, *A2;

      A1 = (float **)calloc(row, sizeof(float *));      // pointer on rows
      A2 = (float *)calloc(row*col, sizeof(float));    // all matrix elements


      for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
          A1[i] = A2 + i*col;

      return A1;
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // random initialisation of matrix with values [0..9]

  void init_mat(float **A, int row, int col)
  {   

      for (int i = 0; i < row*col; i++)
          A[0][i] = (float)(rand() % 10);
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // DEBUG FUNCTION: printout of all matrix elements

  void print_mat(float **A, int row, int col, char *tag)
  {
      int i, j;

      printf("Matrix %s:\n", tag);
      for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
      {

          for (j=0; j<col; j++) 
              printf("%6.1f   ", A[i][j]);
          printf("\n"); 
      }
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      float **A, **B, **C;  // matrices
      int d1, d2, d3;         // dimensions of matrices
      int i, j, k;          // loop variables


      double start, end;
      start = omp_get_wtime();

      /* print user instruction */
      if (argc != 4)
      {
          printf ("Matrix multiplication: C = A x B\n");
          printf ("Usage: %s <NumRowA>; <NumColA> <NumColB>\n",argv[0]); 
           return 0;
       }

       /* read user input */
       d1 = atoi(argv[1]);      // rows of A and C
       d2 = atoi(argv[2]);     // cols of A and rows of B
       d3 = atoi(argv[3]);     // cols of B and C

       printf("Matrix sizes C[%d][%d] = A[%d][%d] x B[%d][%d]\n", 
       d1, d3, d1, d2, d2, d3);

       /* prepare matrices */
       A = alloc_mat(d1, d2);
       init_mat(A, d1, d2); 
       B = alloc_mat(d2, d3);
       init_mat(B, d2, d3);
       C = alloc_mat(d1, d3);   // no initialisation of C, 
   //because it gets filled by matmult

       /* serial version of matmult */
       printf("Perform matrix multiplication...\n");



       int sum;

           for (i = 0; i < d1; i++)
               for (j = 0; j < d3; j++)
                   for (k = 0; k < d2; k++){
                   C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];






       /* test output */
       print_mat(A, d1, d2, "A"); 
       print_mat(B, d2, d3, "B"); 
       print_mat(C, d1, d3, "C"); 

       printf("This task took %f seconds\n", end-start);
       printf ("\nDone.\n");

       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: How about using one of the several well-known, well-tested matrix math libraries?  You could verify your results match, or even better, just use the library instead of your code.  :)

Comment: In this case I am just interested in the numerical algorithm :)

Comment: Well then you can look at the source of an existing library.

Comment: How about multiplying two arbitrary matrices by hand, or with an online tool, or with something free like scilab, and see if your code gets the same result?

Comment: This get's a little elaborate for a big NUM.

Comment: Even if this isn't directly related to your matrix question: you should prefer std::vector<std::vector<int>> over int** in C++ (Stroustrup).

Answer (score 0):

How about using openCV library, you can define matrices of different types and sizes easily using it.

Comment: Is there a particular function in openCV, which checks, wether the result of a matmult is the true result?

Answer (score 0):

Create a random vector `v` and verify that `C * v == A * (B * v)` (but allow some rounding errors).